# Show that is $X_ \alpha$ Hausdorff, regular and normal

Tags: general-topology

Show that if $ \displaystyle \Pi_{\alpha \in J}X_\alpha$ is Hausdorff, or regular, or normal, then so is $X_ \alpha$.

Comment: You need a further assumption, that the factors $X_{\alpha}$ are nonempty.

Comment: JarbasDantasSilva, what have you tried? What do you know about the Tychonoff/product topology?

Comment: the normal and regular cases. What is the face of the closeds

Answer (score 2):

For the Hausdorff and the regular case you can use that $X_\alpha$ is embedded in the product and these properties are hereditary. For the normal case, choose a point $\langle y_i\rangle_{i\in J}$. If $A$ and $B$ are closed disjoint subsets of $X_α$, then $p_α^{-1}[A]$ and $p_α^{-1}[B]$ are closed and disjoint subsets of $\prod_J X_i$, so there are open and disjoint neighborhoods $U$ and $V$. Define $\hat X_α=\left\{x\in\prod_J X_i\mid p_i(x)=y_i, i\neα\right\}$. This space is homeomorphic to $X_α$ via the projection $p_α$. Now $p_α[U\cap\hat X_α]$ and $p_α[V\cap\hat X_α]$ are open and disjoint neighborhoods around $A$ and $B$ respectively.